# Conditional Upserting into a delta sink with Azure Data Flow in Azure Data Factory

Tags: dataflow, delta-lake, azure-data-factory

I have a sink delta in an Azure Data Flow module and the dataframe that I'm using to update it has a hash key for business keys and a hash key for all columns contents.
I want to insert new hash business hash keys to the sink and only update already existing hash key if the content hash key is different (essentially only update if content hash changed for an already existing business key).
Do you think I can somehow do this using "Alter Row Policies"?

I'm mostly looking for a solution that resembles the "Merge" option in pyspark where I can have different policies for when the business key matches or not ([link](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#language-python)).

Also, I'm hoping to avoid joins before writing out to sink; because, I want to avoid having to deal with not having any data in data lake the first time that pipeline runs. I'm writing a template that's reusable for different schemas, so unless I can create an empty dataframe when the sink delta table doesn't exist with a schema that matches the other side of the join, I don't think I can use the join solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (!spark.catalog.tableExists("default", table_name)) {
  spark.sql(s"create table $table_name using delta as select * from source_table_$table_name")
}
else {
  spark.sql(
    s"""
       |MERGE INTO $targetTableName
       |USING $updatesTableName
       |ON $targetTableName.id = $updatesTableName.id
       |WHEN MATCHED THEN
       |  UPDATE SET $targetTableName.ts = $updatesTableName.ts
       |WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       |  INSERT (id, par, ts) VALUES ($updatesTableName.id, $updatesTableName.par, $updatesTableName.ts)
  """.stripMargin)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Which module in data flow should I use to run this piece of code?